# Selectionsort not outputing the right result Python

Tags: python, algorithm, selection-sort

Hello i have been struggling with implementing this selection sort for quite some days now. I feel my code is close to it, but can't figure out why am not getting it.

Here is my code with comments

```
def selectionSort(aList):

    #For each index in the list...
    for i in range(len(aList)):

        #Assume first that current item is already correct...
        minIndex = i

        #For each index from i to the end...
        for j in range(i + 1, len(aList)):

            if aList[j] >= aList[j - 1]:
                break
            aList[j], aList[j - 1] = aList[j - 1], aList[j]
            minIndex = aList.index(aList[j - 1])

        #Save the current minimum value since we're about
        #to delete it
        minValue = aList[minIndex]

        #Delete the minimum value from its current index
        del aList[minIndex]

        #Insert the minimum value at its new index
        aList.insert(i, minValue)

    #Return the resultant list
    return aList
```

This is the result am getting

```
[4, 2, 1, 3, 5]
```

Instead of this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Don't delete and add items in the list you're sorting. Swap them.

Comment: Tip: I believe I read somewhere a long time ago that Ken Thompson (designer and develop of the original Unix) did a lot of his debugging by putting print statements into his code. Need one say more?

Answer (score 0):

```
for j in range(i + 1, len(aList)):

        if aList[j] >= aList[j - 1]:
            break
        aList[j], aList[j - 1] = aList[j - 1], aList[j]
        minIndex = aList.index(aList[j - 1])
```

Selection sort is sorting by iteratively finding the minimum element in the list. Just set the first element as minimum, iterate through the list, if the current element smaller than the minimum then record it as the minimum and record its index. The part after is correct.

Comment: I tried this before posting, it did not work. i mean this line

Comment: minIndex = aList.index(aList[j - 1])

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code guys:

```
def selectionSort(aList):

    #For each index in the list...
    for i in range(len(aList)):

        minIndex = i

        #For each index from i+1 to the end...
        for j in range(i + 1, len(aList)):

            if aList[minIndex] > aList[j]:
            minIndex = j

        #Save the current minimum value since we're about
        #to delete it
        minValue = aList[minIndex]

        #Delete the minimum value from its current index
        del aList[minIndex]

        #Insert the minimum value at its new index
        aList.insert(i, minValue)

    #Return the resultant list
    return aList
```

Thanks once more.
Can't believe that just two lines of code gave me a nightmare. pheew

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to delete and insert, just swap em!

```
def selectionSort(aList):

        #For each index in the list (not the last one)
        for i in range(len(aList)-1):

            #initialized minIndex
            minIndex = i

            #For each index from i+1 to the end...
            for j in range(i + 1, len(aList)):
                #find the min of the list and update minIndex
                if aList[j] < aList[minIndex]:
                    minIndex = j;

            #if minIndex changed, swap i and minIndex values
            if minIndex != i:
                aList[i], aList[minIndex] = aList[minIndex], aList[i]

        #Return the resultant list
        return aList
```